# Odd array formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am participating in a CTF tournament and one of the problems has some js code with this line:

```
result[(j * LEN) + i] = bytes[(((j + shifter) * LEN) % bytes.length) + i]
```

Ignore all the variables. I am confused that an array `results` would have something equalling something in a value. In essence, I am confused about this:

```
Array[a = b]
```

Can someone explain why this is works?

Comment: This is not Array[a = b]. It is more like arr1[a] = arr2[b]. In your code it’s result[a] = bytes[b]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has mis-read the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the nesting levels mixed up.

```
result[(j * LEN)   + i] = bytes[(((j + shifter) * LEN) % bytes.length) + i]
// original code above: it's equivalent to below:
result[(j * LEN)   + i] = rightHandSide
result[(jTimesLen) + i] = rightHandSide
result[jTimesLenPlusI ] = rightHandSide
```

It's just ordinary assignment to an index of the object or array.

Still, `arr[a = b]` would be legal too, just confusing; assignments resolve to expressions, so `arr[a = b]` assigns `b` to the (already existing) variable `a`, and then accesses the `b` index of `arr` (but doesn't do anything after accessing the index).

```js
a = 3;
b = 5;
arr = [];

arr[a = b];

console.log(a);
console.log(arr);
```